# Reduce splash image time IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to reduce standard time (3 seconds) of the default.png image for splash image?

My intention is to set it to 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 12):

There's no standard time for displaying splash screen - it disappears as soon as your application finishes loading and is ready to present its first screen.

To reduce that time you need to optimize loading time of your application (e.g. move some heavy calculation/resource loading to background thread, use lazy-loading etc)

Comment: @JamesWebster Vladimir has clearly optimised his answerDidFinishWriting: method better than you.

Answer (score 7):

1) Defer all processing until the first view has received viewDidAppear.

2) Reduce the number of libraries and frameworks you link to, since the loader takes time at launch.

3) Watch the WWDC 2012 session videos. This topic was covered in depth at one of the Instruments talks (I was in audience). If nothing else the session will show you how to accurately monitor what is going on during launch.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "standard time". The time it is shown is the time until your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` completes.

If you want it to display for less, optimise or offset some loading of that method.

Answer (score 1):

The splashscreen displays during `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is executed. Try to initialize your app in a background method called from `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, like :

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(initApplication:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    return YES;
}

-(void)initApplication {
    ...
}
```

But you may have some black screen before the app graphic initialization!

Answer (score 0):

Just to weigh in here, if you're initializing a bunch of view controllers for a UITabBarController, for example, it's advisable to defer any heavy initialization of these view controller to `viewDidLoad:` instead of their `init:` methods. This way, anything that needs to be allocated and initialized in memory isn't loaded until the view controller is needed.